# Efficient use of (or alternative to) System.IO.MemoryStream

Tags: vb.net, memorystream, imagelist

I have the following code which I am using to populate a `ImageList` from a SQLite database with images stored as blobs.

```
Public Sub populateImagesStyles()

    ShoeImages1.Images.Clear()
    StyleImagesLView.Items.Clear()

    Dim s As SQLiteDataReader
    Dim rcount As Integer = 0
    dbLocalQuery = New SQLiteCommand("SELECT id, image FROM tblImages", dbLocal)
    s = dbLocalQuery.ExecuteReader()

    While s.Read()
        rcount += 1
        ShoeImages1.Images.Add(CStr(s("id")), byte2img(s("image")))
        StyleImagesLView.Items.Add(CStr(s("id")), CStr(s("id")))

    End While
    s.Close()
```

Here is the byte2img function...

```
Public Function byte2img(ByVal imgByte As Byte()) As Image
    Dim imgMemoryStream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(imgByte)
    byte2img = Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgMemoryStream)
End Function
```

The database contains over 250 images and this process is completed twice on load to populate two different `ImageList`, because I need the images displayed at two different sizes.

When the process runs on loading the form, it causes the process to consume between 800MB and 1GB of system memory, unless I manually run the process again from an form control, which seems to trigger garbage collection.

Stepping through the loading process, it is clear that it is the byte2img process that is causing the memory usage to escalate - what is the best way to mitigate this?

Also, if anyone can think of a more efficient process to execute this, i'm all ears. The images have to be stored in the database file because I need to be able to just package the .db file and send it to a remote location at a moments notice, so I can't mess with folders with images.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to load all the images at once?  Could you use paging on your form so you get the first 10 images, then go on to the next 10 etc...?

Comment: if you have images stored in a DB why load them all into the app?  cant you fetch them from the DB as needed, perhaps saving them once they have been retrieved so it need not be repeated.

Comment: The images are read out into the two ImageLists, as detailed in the post. This is part of the CRUD functionality on the database - users can modify records and pick images to be associated with other data by clicking on them.

If there is a way of paging data into a `ImageList` or retrieving more data after you scroll to the bottom of the current `ListView`, then i'm all ears.

Comment: The OP makes no mention of a  ListView, but they do support a Virtual mode; I'm not sure you could dynamically load an imagelist as needed though.  One issue is in `byte2img`

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, I see I did not mention the `ListView` but didn't feel it was relevant because it's only used to display the contents of the `ImageList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution/workaround that seems to work - call the `PopulateImageStyles` sub when a user visits the specific `TabPage` the `ImageList` resides on.

For some arbitrary reason, when run this way (as above, when called on the form), the process never proceeds to consume more than 50-60 MB of working memory.

I'll add a Background Worker so that the process can execute without hanging the form.

Answer (score 4):

You are creating a lot of memory streams without disposing of them.  Try this:

```
Public Function byte2img(ByVal imgByte As Byte()) As Image
   Dim img As Image

   Try
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(imgbyte)
            img = Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
        End Using      ' auto dispose of the MS
    Catch ex As Exception
         ' report possibly bad/missing imgByte()
         ' resulting in an error in either place
    End Try

    Return img
End Function
```

An imprecise way to detect this kind of thing is to watch the HANDLES count in TaskManager.

Comment: Also make sure that Drawing.Image.FromStream might throw an ArgumentException. Maybe also mention the garbage collector.

Comment: @FabianBigler good point; personally I'd check the DB Column before calling this, but yes it might be garbled or incomplete.  What about GC?

Comment: It's certainly a lot faster loading with this code in place, but the running memory usage is still between 850 & 950 MB until I repeat the Populate process, which causes it to drop down to a more reasonable ~150 MB.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's probably worth adding that because I have two `ImageLists` querying the same data, the memory usage is understandingly doubled. It still, however, does not really explain why running the populate process manually cuts down on this memory usage - i've set up some memory logging against the process and GC and I can see when the memory usage drops down, but it's inconsistent and I cannot see why.